# Solitaire Game: Transferring Cards Design in C++

Tags: c++, architecture

So, I'm working on a Solitaire game. I already created a the classes: Card, Pile, Stock. Each work as expected on it's own. My question is: What possible design for managing moving card(s) between the 7 piles, the stock (the waste) and the foundations? I want a possible design that is suitable for managing these game objects so they can work together smoothly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make a game class that would contain the Pile and Stock objects and transfer the cards in that class. You could probably use SendTo function in Pile and Stock classes for transferring the cards between them.

Comment: I like it. Do you have any expressive class names?

Comment: Those are just names. Who cares...

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: Why are `Pile` and `Stock` even different classes? Is there a fundamental difference in how they hold cards? Why not have a single `CardStack` that your piles and stock both use, with events they can hook into for managing gameplay?

Comment: Yes, there are differences between them. For example, `Pile` is implemented using `std::vector` while `Stock` is implemented using `std::list`. I agree with you, it would be nice to have a class that they both inherit from. Anyway, I already solved the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you are over-complicating/over-thinking the design. KISS.

Comment: Are you saying that I should replace std::list with std::vector and add an extra layer of inheritance by moving the common data members to a base class to simplify things? What about events? How can I hook them up? Would you please elaborate more in a separate answer post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. Actually, I was inspired by the Observer pattern. I created a class `TransferringSystem`. It contains references to each pile, foundation, and the stock. As for the behavior, it contains three function overloads of `update` function, one for `Pile`, one for `Stock` and one for `Foundation`. Each of the three classes will register itself to the system. When an entity is released, it will tell the system that it was released by passing `this` to it. The system will be responsible for checking if a selected entity intersects with other entities and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward and simplest way is a pretty good design: have a data type that is a list of cards (could be a vector, linked list, or other things) and move cards between card groups as gameplay dictates. Unless you have a reason to go in a different direction, simple is good and will make for less bugs.  Even if you need super high performance for your card game (you shouldn't) a linked list will be plenty fast (:

Comment: Let me clarify, I know what data structure to use. Also, I am not worried too much about performance since it's just a state-based game. My problem is with coming up with a concept like a manager class.

Comment: Well, I think the important things to focus on would be to make the logic that moves the cards around contained in a single class or group of classes, make sure the public interface is similar to the options a player would have when playing the game (aka simple interface that makes logical sense as far as solitaire actions you can do) and that things like input and rendering are handled in completely different, isolated pieces of code.  Other than that I think the answer is "just do it", Nike style.

Comment: BTW if you have specific concerns with the design, or specific problems you are trying to tackle, you might be able to get more targeted answers

Comment: I think I would rather hear an answer about a single class or group of classes that make the logic of moving the cards around easy. Other than that, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't have any conditions. Any design that doesn't make my code look like a spaghetti.